# Check latest file updates in directory on linux using bash shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, boolean

I have basic knowledge of linux bash shell scripting, right now I am facing a problem that is like following:

1. Suppose I am working in an empty directory **mydir**
2. Then there is a process which is created by a C program to generate a file with one word. (Exp: file.txt would have one word, "hello")
3. Routinely, after a specific period of time, the file is updated by the C program with the same one word "hello".
4. I want check the file every time when it is updated.
5. But the issue is that I also want my script doing some other operation while checking the file updates and when it detects file updates that it returns something for which I can use to trigger something else.

So, can anyone help me.

Also, some proof of concept :

```
while true;
do 
    func1();
    func2();
    check file is updated or not 
    if updated ; then
       break;
     else
      continue;
```

Comment: You'll want to investigate [inotifywait](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/inotifywait.1.html)

Comment: Avoid `while true...` loops to check file creation/modification under linux and use notify. It's much more efficient... Have a look [here](http://techarena51.com/index.php/inotify-tools-example/)

Comment: @mauro : but inotifywait is blocking I not want blocking and thanks for replying .

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `stat` command. Do `man stat` to see how yours works. You want to look for "modtime" or "time of last data modification" option. For mine that would be `stat -c%Y file`. Something like `basemodtime=$(stat -c%Y file)` before the loop, `modtime=$(stat -c%Y file)` after `func2()`, and then `if [ $modtime != $basemodtime ]; then` to detect "updated".

Comment: that is working for me . I have just basic knowledge about bash and shell scripting . Can you give me some suggestion for how I can got more about bash or linux api scripting  ??

Comment: This comes up at the top when I google "online bash manual": https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html